# Zelda received a bizarre postcard

Tags: steganography, video-games

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Your highness..                                    /\       |
| Princess Zelda, I'm sorry for the delay. Is       /  \      |
| it wrong of me to quit, possibly. In another     /____\     |
| reality perhaps I'll save you. Another day,     /\    /\    |
| another life, a better Link. Castle Hyrule is  /  \  /  \   |
| surrounded by evil.                           /____\/____\  |
|                                                             |
| Oh princess, my failures are my own, but they have affected |
| you, the one I pledged to save, as your appointed knight.   |
| I have re-taken the Divine Beasts, but Calamity Gannon is   |
| simply too strong. Please Zelda, run. Flee this disaster.   |
| Find new champions, a new knight, that can better serve you.|
| I, we, your chosen, can no longer save you.                 |
|                                                             |
| We. Have. Failed. You.                                      |
|                                                             |
| No, I have failed you.                                      |
|                                                             |
| Zelda, I'm sorry.                                           |
|                                                             |
| I should have been faster, better, stronger, for you, to    |
| save you, I should have tried harder. But I didn't.         |
|                                                             |
| From your failed knight,                                    |
| Link                                                        |
|        Post to: Floor 2 - Wing 15 - Corridor 17 - Room 10   |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

> Zelda was busily fighting Gannon when she received this ridiculous postcard from Link. **Why can't link save her?**

Comment: I can't find much, but someone else will probably be able to: here's a paste of only ., (morse code maybe?), save some work https://pastebin.com/5ibkX0cr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is:

> Link doesn't remember Zelda

I believe this to be the case based on two hints.

1)

> As "thecoder16" states in the comments, removing everything but the characters "." and "," gives a morse code message, changing the commas (,) to dashes (-)

2)

> The "Post to:" address at the end contains the numbers 2, 15, 17, 10, which happen to add to 44, the same length as the morse code message

So using these hints,

> Break up the morse code message into four blocks of lengths from hint (2) to get .. -.-..--..----.- .-..--.---.....-. -.-----..-

and then

> convert this to English to get the phrase "I can't remember you"

I'm honestly not sure if this is right but it seemed to work out well enough.

Comment: 100% correct! It makes more sense if you'd played BOTW, specifically.